# Preimage of a sequence of cauchy

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $X,Y$ metric spaces. 
If $f:X\to{Y}$  is continuous, and $\{y_n\}$ is  a Cauchy sequence in $Y$. 
Then, my question is $\{f^{-1}(y_n)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X$?

I´m sorry, in a second thought, f is surjective and suppose X is complete.

Any suggestion or a counterexample.

Thank you all.

Comment: 1) Is your map surjective, or do you assume that each $y_n$ lies in the image?  Otherwise the question doesn't make sense.  2) Have you thought about what happens when the sequence $\{y_n\}$ is constant?  3) If you assume that $X$ and $Y$ are complete, you can replace "Cauchy" with "convergent", which seems to make things easier to think about.  Must the preimage of a convergent sequence under a continuous map be convergent?

Comment: For a fixed $n$, $f^{-1}(y_n)$ is a set of points. For instance, imagine $f: \mathbb{R} \to \{p\}$. There is no "sequence" in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Perhaps better to say that $\Bbb R$ is not a sequence.

Comment: No: let $f(x)=1/x\; \text {for} \; x>0$ and $\;y_n=1/n$.